# Solving the Diophantine equation $7x+4y=100$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I have attempted to solve this Diophantine equation:

[image]

But the solution I got is different from the one given above, my general solution is:

$x = -100 + 4t$ & $y = 200 - 7t$ , is the solution given above is correct or my solution is correct ? could anyone check this for me?

**Note:**

In my solution I have found the greatest common divisor of 4 and 7, which is 1 and then I have written it as a linear combination of 7 and 4, then I have multiplied the resulting equation by 1.

This is from the book of David M. Burton "elementary number theory", seventh edition, pg.37

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are correct, is just different parametrizations of the same thing. Your solution is $x=-100+4t=4(t-25)$, $y=200-7t=25-7(t-25)$

Comment: what is the parametrization used here? How can we define it ?

Comment: I don't understand your question, the only thing I am saying here is that the solutions $(x,y)$ are parameterized by some parameter $t\in\mathbb{Z}$. But there are different parameterizations for the same set of points. The book is giving one way and if you make a change of variables $t\to t-25$, you get your parameterization.

Comment: Thank you I got it now :)